# convert time from sqlite UTC to csv local time

Tags: python

Database is UTC, 
my python code:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
import sys

conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/talo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

data = cur.execute('select time, value from talo_data where position_id=1 AND DATETIME([time]) >= DATETIME("now","-1 day");')

with open('/home/log/my.csv', 'wb') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(['date', 'value'])
  writer.writerows(data)
for row in data:
 print >> f, row
```

my csv file UTC, must be local time:

```
date,value
2013-08-11 06:10:00,17.9375
2013-08-11 06:20:00,17.625
2013-08-11 06:30:00,18.0625
2013-08-11 06:40:00,19.4375
2013-08-11 06:50:00,19.4375
2013-08-11 07:00:00,18.6875
2013-08-11 07:10:00,19.8125
2013-08-11 07:20:00,19.5
2013-08-11 07:30:00,19.75
```

how i convert/do to csv file time +3 hours to my local time ?

Answer (score 0):

In short use datetime.datetime.strptime(str, fmt)

```
>>> (datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-08-11 06:10:00,179375', "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S,%f")+datetime.timedelta(hours=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S,%f')
```

In long this will be a three step process:-

1. Convert the seconds in your date to a non decimal point format so that datetime.datetime.strptime understands it
2. Add/Subtract 3 hours using datetime.timedelta
3. Output using strftime